# New Server. Umbraco aspx-files return 404

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco

I have a new server since yesterday and want to run umbraco on it. I installed a clean instance (download from our.umbraco.com). The installation worked fine (mysql database).

I created a new document-type but I can't work on the templates. It looks to me as some or all of the aspx-files are blocked.

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So my plesk had a button to resolve this. Sadly i don't know what it does exactly. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It was most likely that some of the filesystem permissions were not set correctly on the directories on the server. You should be able to see this in the health check dashboard of the developer section if you run into this issue another time.

It also seems likely that this was the issue, as it was something Plesk was able to fix by a one-click action.

[image: Health Check dashboard]